# Cron Job (Quartz.NET) in .NET is not triggering daily

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have scheduled a cron Job in .NET and the same is hosted in IIS. On the first day it has triggered ( for testing purpose i actually send mail when this job is triggered). But the next day it has not (i want this to be recursive on daily basis ... every 24 Hrs once) Please find the code below.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Error("-------------------------------------------Inside JobScheduler Start-------------------------------------------");

            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<QualityGateSFDCActionJob>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1").WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(11, 42)).ForJob(job).Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            Logger.Error("-------------------------------------------Scheduler Started without Issues-------------------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Some on kindly help on this.

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1").WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(11, 42)).ForJob(job).Build();
```

I just want this job to run daily in the morning 11:42 AM. I would be thank full for any help in this regard

Application is built up on ASP.NET MVC and hosted on IIS. I want a job to be run on a daily basis, That's why i choose Cron Job (Windows service is out of context/scope in my production server)

Comment: I think this is IIS related, cause it will recycle the application pool after some time and your job won´t trigger anymore. Do you use a static class for this? Long-running task should not run in the IIS more in an external service or so

Comment: I agree with Jehof, possibly to do with IIS recycling. When are you calling this Start() method? Does it require you to do something manually ie. Call a service?

Comment: Thanks Jehof & CathalMF for your quick reply. Yes, we will be calling a service (REST API) to post data. It should be happen on a daily basis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS has a feature called "Recycling". This basically reloads everything in IIS.

If you go into Advanced Settings of your Application Pool in the IIS Manager there is an Recycling Interval which by default is 1740 minutes (29 hours)

When IIS Recycles, your application will not begin running until something calls the webservice. So once every 29 hours it will recycle, so depending on when you started your webservice it will run your Cron job once or twice but never a 3rd time unless you have called your webservice after the recycle to restart it.

Basically, IIS is not a good place to host an application which needs to be always running jobs.

Comment: there are other causes too for an IIS app pool to recycle, for example rapid fail protection (after a configurable number of unhandled exceptions) or recycle after a configurable number of requests... to get it reliable, the timers should certainly be hosted in a dedicated service process.

Comment: Thanks CathalMF for your reply. So, you mean to say CRON Job is not a good idea to do so on IIS??? i have choosed this because i have no permission /rights to do (windows service , or sql job on my production server). Please suggest

Comment: is it IIS8? then with Application Initialization, you might be able to execute initialization code after a recycle and thus "resurrect" your timers: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive